# Can't run Java with specific dependecy

Tags: java, intellij-idea, pom.xml, cucumber-serenity

I use Intellij 2018.1 and when i add to my project a serenity-cucumber dependency with latest versions, the run and debug button doesn't work anymore. (It's strange that maven it's able to run the tests with no problem).

I tried and built the simplest project with hello world and just with that dependency. No success, same situation. When i've gone to version 1.9.8(maybe there are newer versions that could work, i will try), the intellij started to work normal.

Also tried to change project sdk and project language level.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.35</version>
<dependency>
```

Now the program works with that older version, but it doesn't generate the report well. Maybe i will find a solution to run the tests with intellij with debug mode using last version.

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"? Any errors in the IDE or in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085)?

Comment: I press the button and doesn't start anything. Event log window is clear, no log is added. I should look in another place?

Comment: [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085)

Comment: Also I will try to reproduce on another laptop after work, and come back with info.

Comment: Try with 2019.1.1 version. If the issue persists, share the IDE logs and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Updated to 2019.1  and now it works.